# Send transictional email of backend programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, email, backend, transactional-mail

I'm trying to send programmatically transitional emails that I created in the backend.

I did some research and saw many examples of sending emails programmatically only for those in html format.

How can I send my emails created in the backend programmatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This an example of how Magento handles the shipment email.

**Path to file:** \vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender.php

```
public function send(Shipment $shipment, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $shipment->setSendEmail($this->identityContainer->isEnabled());

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
            $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());

            $transport = [
                'order' => $order,
                'shipment' => $shipment,
                'comment' => $shipment->getCustomerNoteNotify() ? $shipment->getCustomerNote() : '',
                'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
                'store' => $order->getStore(),
                'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
                'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
                'order_data' => [
                    'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
                    'is_not_virtual' => $order->getIsNotVirtual(),
                    'email_customer_note' => $order->getEmailCustomerNote(),
                    'frontend_status_label' => $order->getFrontendStatusLabel()
                ]
            ];
            $transportObject = new DataObject($transport);

            /**
             * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
             */
            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'email_shipment_set_template_vars_before',
                ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transportObject->getData(), 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
            );

            $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

            if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->shipmentResource->saveAttribute($shipment, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $shipment->setEmailSent(null);
            $this->shipmentResource->saveAttribute($shipment, 'email_sent');
        }

        $this->shipmentResource->saveAttribute($shipment, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }
```

I think you have to do something similar to this. Let me know if you need any further help.

UPDATE:

The class **Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container** is responsible to provide the template info so you need to create an instance of this class and pass it on to the send function above.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container;

class Template
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $vars;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $templateId;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Set email template variables
     *
     * @param array $vars
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTemplateVars(array $vars)
    {
        $this->vars = $vars;
    }

    /**
     * Set email template options
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTemplateOptions(array $options)
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * Get email template variables
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTemplateVars()
    {
        return $this->vars;
    }

    /**
     * Get email template options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTemplateOptions()
    {
        return $this->options;
    }

    /**
     * Set email template id
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTemplateId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Get email template id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTemplateId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi man! Thanks for the reply. What I would like is to understand how to send a transitional email in my custom module by taking the id of the email created in the backend. In this example Magento takes template in html right?

Comment: just updated my answer, let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: Okay, I'll let you know as soon as I tried. Thank you

Comment: Don't mean to nag you but please, if this solved your issue mark it as answer, if not let me know how I can help ;)

Comment: Sorry man, you're right, but I still haven't been able to test your code. As soon as I have done it, I will update you :)

Comment: If you need any further assistance let me know ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! ;)